# How to change color in react on button click using state

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

i have set up state to change the color of my background

```
const [bgClr, setBgClr] = useState('white');
```

The button whose background colors needs to be changed is

```
<Button
            onClick={AnnualHandler}
            variant="outline-light"
            style={{ background: {bgClr} }}>
            <div
              className="pt-3 pb-3 ml-3 mr-3"
              style={{ background: '#f8f9fa' }}>
              <h4 style={{ color: 'var(--main)' }}>
                <b>$ 15</b>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </Button>
```

and the handler is

```
const AnnualHandler = () => {
    setBgClr('yellow');
    console.log(bgClr);
  };
```

But on clicking, the background color is not changing.
Should useEffect be used here?

Comment: try this ` `background: ${bgClr}` `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done like this:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [bgClr, setBgClr] = React.useState("white");

  const annualHandler = () => {
    setBgClr("yellow");        
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={annualHandler}
        variant="outline-light"
        style={{ background: { bgClr } }}
      >
        <div className="pt-3 pb-3 ml-3 mr-3" style={{ background: bgClr }}>
          <h4 style={{ color: "var(--main)" }}>
            <b>$ 15</b>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in your code is the way you set the `bgClr` value to the background of the button.

```js
<Button style={{ background: {bgClr} }}>
```

Don't do that. Just directly set `bgClr` to the Button like this.

```js
<Button style={{ background: bgClr }}>
```

**Note :-**

```js
const AnnualHandler = () => {
   setBgClr('yellow');
   console.log(bgClr);
};
```

The above code snippet shows to us that you’re trying to get the updated state after the `setBgClr` run. But it won’t happen because State updates in React are asynchronous. So that you will get the old value even after you change the colour to `yellow`.

Resource - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

**Full Code**

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [bgClr, setBgClr] = useState("white");

  const AnnualHandler = () => {
    setBgClr("yellow");
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={AnnualHandler} style={{ background: bgClr }}>
      Change
    </button>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/change-the-color-of-the-button-69327076-wpgyj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the actual value of `bgClr`, while you assigning an object:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: bgClr }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correct but only the css attribute `background`

```
style={{ background: bgClr }}
```

The correct way is

```
style={{ backgroundColor: bgClr }}>
```